# HTML/JS Debugger

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, internet-explorer

We are searching for an HTML/JS debugger specifically suited for IE that can handle popup windows as well. We tested Firebug Lite which is good but it has its restrictions when compared to Firebug. We also tried IE Companion but there are some problems when it comes to in-place editing and popups.

Do you recommend a good debugger?

Comment: This question has been asked a lot on stackoverflow, too bad the search turns up unrelated stuff.

Comment: It would help to mention the version of IE you want to debug in future posts.

Comment: We are targeting IE7 and higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 has one built in, it can run as IE7 also. Hit f12

Comment: IE8 debugger is the best one I have used so far. Internet Explorer Toolbar is also good but certainly IE8 debugger has more features than this!

Answer (score 2):

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE_Developer_Toolbar). It is best for IE as of i know so far :)

[alt text http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d1/Devtoolbar.PNG](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d1/Devtoolbar.PNG)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. This is very useful. However, till now I have problems with it when it comes to popup windows. The toolbar is hidden in popup windows. I am not sure it there is an option to enable it again in popups?

Comment: you can enable it in popups too, see it's documentation

Comment: I just hit CTRL+N and it becomes available for popups

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? It's called the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), it's like FireBug... but it's not that good :D

Comment: It's rubbish, that's what it is..
But that's the only thing for IE I know of

Answer (score 0):

If (like me) you can make do with logging as a debugging tool, [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org) works well.